# What is the logic behind this regular expression from a web scraper function: ("^(http|www)((?!("+linkParse+")).)*$")

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I was studying an example in a web scraping text book. the function of the web scraper is to get external links on a webpage.

I redefined the function in a simpler format I can understand but one line of regular expression keeps confusing me. the whole function is written below.

```
url = "http://oreilly.com"

url_parse = urlparse(url)

external_links = set()

def scrape_external(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")
    linkParse = url_parse.netloc
    #this is the line I need some clarity below
    externalLinks = bsObj.findAll("a",{"href": re.compile("^(http|www)((?!"+linkParse+").)*$")})
    for i in externalLinks:
        if "href" in i.attrs:
            link = i.attrs['href']
            external_links.add(link)
        
    print(external_links)

scrape_external(url)
```

From my own understanding that regular expression line means "to only match http or www when it's not followed by the home url". but I need more in-depth on how the whole thing works or the logic behind it... I know the meaning of the symbols but I have some troubles putting the whole thing together. particularly the "* and $" symbols.

For instance, why do i need to put the dollar sign at the end and why does it makes so much difference in my results when I remove it.

This is my first question on here and I'm still very new to python. Thanks

Comment: ^ asserts position at start of a line i.e. starts with,  * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy), $ asserts position at the end of a line i.e. ends with. Moving, for example, $ changes the meaning.

Comment: That's awful code, you want urljoin to convert links not regex, also your url_parse is out of scope, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [`regexr`](https://regexr.com/43a6a) link that explains the syntax.

### Understanding the Weird Symbols

> `^` matches the beginning of the string.
>
> `$` matches the end of the string.

This makes a lot of difference, since having that would match the **entire** string, instead of just a substring.

> `(http|www)` matches `http` OR `www`
>
> `(?!` ... `)` is what's called a *negative lookahead*. It "specifies a group that can not match after the main expression (if it matches the result is discarded)".

For example, `t(?!s)` matches the first `t` in `streets` but not the second `t` because the lookahead found an `s` after that second `t`.

> `.` will match any character (alphanumeric, symbols, except the newline `'\n'`).
>
> `*` will match 0 or more instances of the above, *negative lookahead*.

[I believe] `linkParse` turns out to be `oreilly.com`.

`((?!(oreilly.com)).)*` will keep matching characters **as long as** it isn't followed by `oreilly.com`.

### Testing the Regex

So parsing the regex, scrutinising the context, and trying this on my IDLE, we can observe that the regex would match external links

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("^(http|www)((?!oreilly.com).)*$")
>>> m = r.match('https://www.google.com')
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(0, 22), match='https://www.google.com'>
>>> m = r.match('https://www.google.com/food')
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(0, 27), match='https://www.google.com/food'>
>>> m = r.match('https://oreilly.com/tests')
>>> m
>>> type(m)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> m = r.match('https://oreally.com')
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='https://oreally.com'>
```

The regex would not match any links containing `oreilly.com`, so is ***guaranteed*** to only return external links. However, it wouldn't match *external links **containing*** `oreilly.com`. For example:

```
>>> m = r.match('https://www.google.com/search?q=memes+oreilly.com')
>>> m
>>> type(m)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

So one might question the extent to which it matches external links.

I'm not sure how BeautifulSoup parses the regex, but I'm guessing that it may be similar.

### The Dollar Sign `$` at the End

You were also wondering about the dollar sign at the end. Here's an example of a **internal link** being *unintentionally* matched.

```
>>> r = re.compile("^(http|www)((?!oreilly.com).)*")
>>> m = r.match('https://oreilly.com/tests')
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='https://'>
```

Why? It's because the regex matched `https://`, meaning it matched `0` instances of `((?!oreilly.com).)`. This makes sense, since remember, `*` means "match 0 or more instances of [an expression]". Now you see why the dollar sign is crucial, because it forces the entire string to be matched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... particularly on the "$" symbol. I will still have to do further studies on how it relates to strings and sub-strings. and your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your further answers

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it's not as simple as understanding what the symbols mean, rather than what they do in the context of the situation. Glad that you found this useful.